# What are the resistor values that I should use in order to get 38dB gain?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, ltspice, npn

I have build a common emitter-common collector multistage BJT amplifier.

I want to get an output gain of 38 dB under the conditions of 8 ohms load resistance, 6 volts, 25 mVpp input voltage signal. What are the resistor values I should choose to get 38 dB?

Comment: If you have built it, post the schematic and the resistors you did use and what gain it already has.  Also why you need 38dB.  Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, and we don't hand out homework solutions here. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, show **all** of your work, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: i have build the circuit and got the gain close to 32dB. but i cant get the close value for 38dB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

40 dB is 100:1 is close enuf, but that CE/CC amp won’t give you the current gain with feedback that you haven’t specified.

Typically a speaker power amp has a damping factor of 100 which means the woofer is damped if you have one , such that back EMF current is reduced 99% or the driver output impedance is 1% of the speaker or 80 mohms roughly.

Hypothetically this means for an input impedance of say 8 kohms to 8 ohms the current gain must be >1000 or 60 dB in current gain.  Thus your total power gain is 40+60 = 100 dB . Make sense?

All power amps generally use complementary Darlingtons to provide the current gain with 2 or 3 stages of emitter followers. hence the max swing is reduced from the supply rails,

- this is why Class D is more popular.

Comment: but i got gain as 32dB

Comment: huh?  you need both V and I gain